# Does 'but' require a comma before it in this context?

Tags: conjunctions

From the Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation

> Adverbs are words that modify everything but nouns and pronouns.

I'm **okay** with this structure because I use *but* quite often in this way...

> I can bear anything but hunger (The hunger is the **only** thing I cannot bear, rest all is **okay** with me!).

But I remember that a native speaker did not understand this at first and when I explained, she asked me to put a **comma** before *but*. Having this said,

> I can bear anything, but hunger - makes sense and is understandable.

If that's the case, the first example from the book is *my way* and not the way she advised.

Your input please.

Comment: Hey @maulik-v, my question ll be out of this context whereas, can you explain the meaning of **'but'** in this sentence? Is this 'but' similar to 'except'?

Comment: @Hakan yes, *but* refers to 'except' here! I want anything but Coke means I can have anything but NOT coke!

Comment: That's what the question was. And the answer is -NO. It does not require it.

Answer (score 5):

Your native speaker is, sadly, quite wrong.

The sentence *I can bear anything, but hunger.* leaves me hanging because the use of the comma before "but" signals that it is introducing an independent clause.  In other words, I expect it to continue something like *but hunger is the most burdensome*; the sudden appearance of the period is quite jarring and unexpected.

When a coordinating conjunction such as *but* is used to link a pair of words (in this case, *anything* and *hunger*) no comma should be used.

http://www.towson.edu/ows/conjunctions.htm has some further information about coordinating conjunctions.

Answer (score 0):

This looks good to me:

> I can bear anything but hunger.